# ansible ios_command timeout when doing "show conf" on cisco 3850

Tags: ansible, cisco

I've got a simple ansible playbook that works fine on most ios devices.  It fails on some of my 3850 switches with what looks like a timeout when doing a "show conf".  How do I specify a longer, non-default timeout for command completion with the ios_command module (and presumably also ios_config)?

Useful details:

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: ios_devices
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: OBTAIN LOGIN CREDENTIALS
    include_vars: secrets.yaml

  - name: DEFINE PROVIDER
    set_fact:
      provider:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ creds['username'] }}"
        password: "{{ creds['password'] }}"

  - name: LIST NAME SERVERS
    ios_command:
      provider: "{{ provider }}"
      commands: "show run | inc name-server"
    register: dns_servers

  - debug: var=dns_servers.stdout_lines
```

successful run:

> $ ansible-playbook listnameserver.yaml -i inventory/onehost
>
> PLAY [ios_devices] *****************************************************************************************************************
>
> TASK [OBTAIN LOGIN CREDENTIALS] ****************************************************************************************************
>   ok: [iosdevice1.example.com]
>
> TASK [DEFINE PROVIDER] *************************************************************************************************************
>   ok: [iosdevice1.example.com]
>
> TASK [LIST NAME SERVERS] ***********************************************************************************************************
>   ok: [iosdevice1.example.com]
>
> TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************
>   ok: [iosdevice1.example.com] => {
>       "dns_servers.stdout_lines": [
>           [
>               "ip name-server 10.1.1.166", 
>               "ip name-server 10.1.1.168"
>           ]
>       ]
>   }
>
> PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************
>   iosdevice1.example.com : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

unsuccessful run:

> $ ansible-playbook listnameserver.yaml -i inventory/onehost
>
> PLAY [ios_devices] *****************************************************************************************************************
>
> TASK [OBTAIN LOGIN CREDENTIALS] ****************************************************************************************************
>   ok: [iosdevice2.example.com]
>
> TASK [DEFINE PROVIDER] *************************************************************************************************************
>   ok: [iosdevice2.example.com]
>
> TASK [LIST NAME SERVERS] ***********************************************************************************************************
>   fatal: [iosdevice2.example.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "timeout trying to send command: show run | inc name-server", "rc": 1}
>           to retry, use: --limit @/home/sample/ansible-playbooks/listnameserver.retry
>
> PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************
>   iosdevice2.example.com : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Answer (score 0):

The default timeout is 10 seconds if the request takes longer than this ios_command will fail.

You can add the timeout as a key in the provider variable, like this:

```
- name: DEFINE PROVIDER
  set_fact:
    provider:
      host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      username: "{{ creds['username'] }}"
      password: "{{ creds['password'] }}"
      timeout: 30
```

Comment: Excellent!  Worked great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you've already got a timeout value in provider here's a handy way to update only that key in the variable.

```
- name: Update existing provider timeout key
  set_fact:
     provider: "{{ provider | combine( {'timeout': '180'} ) }}"
```